# Is the sum of functions with compact support a function that has compact support as well?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that have compact support. If $f, g \in C(\mathbb{R})$, then is it true that
$f+g \in C(\mathbb{R})$?

I am just wondering. Because nothing is said about this set to be a vector space. Nor did I ever encounter in my real analysis class that speaks about $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ being a vector space.
Obviously, the sum will vanish at a certain boundary. But does it also follow that the sum will have compact support?

EDIT: whoops. it turns out that $C_c$ is a vector space. However my question still remains: Is the set of functions with compact support closed under addition? Or a much stronger question, is it a vector space?

Answer (score 1):

In any commutative topological group, $K+F$ is closed whenever $K$ is compact and $F$ is closed. Note that compact sets in ${\bf{R}}^{n}$ are exactly those closed and bounded sets, so if $F$ is compact as well, then the whole $K+F$ is bounded.

Comment: No, if $0\leq f\leq 1$ has compact support in $[0,1]$ and $g=-f$, then $f+g=0$ which has compact support the empty set.